# save data from an external device to arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote the following function which reads a buffer from an external device (I have opened the serial port with another function). I have this for loop because I want to have non stop results:

```
int get_data(int fd)
{
  int n;

for (;;)
 {
   char buff[1000];
   n=read(fd,buff,1000);
   printf("%s\n\n", buff);
   sleep(1);
   memset(buff, 0, 1000);
 }
}
```

The buffer returns every 10 seconds different results like this:

```
machine 1:vol=3.44V, str=10.2
machine 2:vol=3.23V, str=10.00
```

After 10 seconds

```
machine 1:vol=3.24V, str=11.2
machine 1:vol=3.27V, str=11.4
```

etc.

My question now is, how can I save in an array all the vol values and in a second array the str values? As a next step is to save these data from the arrays in a mysql database. I thought to use strncpy to copy the strings in a new array but I think it is a not a good idea. For example:

```
char vol[10];
strncpy(vol, buff + 15, 4);
printf("%s\n", vol);
```

What do you have to propose me?

Comment: You can use `strtok` to delimit the output.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok
Space can be your delimiter, not sure what parts you want to save to the array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I want to save in the first array the numbers 3.44, 3.27 etc and in the second 10.2, 10.00 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could something like this be of use? It's very crude but sort of gets the job done (or at least it demonstrates the use of `strtok`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string [] = "machine 1:vol=13.271V, str=11.41";
    char buffer_a[25] = "";
    char buffer_b[25] = "";
    char* ptr;

    ptr = strtok(string, " ,=Vvol:strmachine()");


    int i = 0;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ,=Vvol:strmachine()");

        if (i == 0)
            strcat(buffer_a, ptr); // copies vol

        if (i == 1)
            strcat(buffer_b, ptr); // copies str

        i++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", buffer_a);

    printf("%s\n", buffer_b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
$ ./a.out 
13.271
11.41
```

Comment: Very useful code...It works as I want. But one more question. If I have char string [] = "machine 1:(vol=13.271V, str=11.41)"; how can I declere the () in the strtok?

Comment: I've just tested it with the following:
`strtok(string, " ,=Vvol:strmachine()");` and it seems to work, in `strtok` you can declare the characters in any order :)
Please try it and confirm if it works for you.

Comment: I wanted exactly strmachine() which you changed it in strtok. Again thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to have been of help :)

Comment: For my background one last question. If I have char string [] = "My name is Peter.machine 1:(vol=13.271V, str=11.41)"; is there any way to escape all this text 'My name is Peter' and continue exactly in the machine 1 as you send me? Or is doesn't matter if we have text like this?

Comment: `strtok` will return basically every character that is not in the list, so if you were to make the list look like this -  `"MynameisPeter.machine ,=Vvol:str()"` then the additional characters will be escaped properly. In my case `char string [] = "My name is Peter.machine 1:(vol=13.271V, str=11.41)";` returned the two numbers just like above :)

Comment: I added another external machine which sends me exactly same data but with an additional line. Think something like char string [] = "Data send(051)/n machine 1:(vol=13.271V, str=11.41)"; I did exactly the same like your above example and it works. But sometimes the machine sends me different values for Data send() for example 043, 075 etc and not 051. Here I have problem. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Are you trying to trim the zero? Just add it to the list in this case. Otherwise it should work, can you please give me your `strok()` delimiters?

Comment: Ok. My device sends every 5 seconds this but with different values char string [] = "+PARAMETERS:80 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (051)\nMachine_1:(vol=13.271V, str=11.41)"; and I wrote this ptr = strtok (string, "+DATA:80BYTESFROM0000:0000()\nMachine ,=Vol:str()"); but sometimes it is not send 051 but 024 or 045 or 030.

Comment: I forgot to write 051 in strtok ptr = strtok (string, "+DATA:80BYTESFROM0000:0000(051)\nMachine ,=Vol:str()");

Comment: Can you try changing the first `i` to 3 from 0, and the second to 4 from 1?

Comment: Ok this is my setup:
`char string [] = "+PARAMETERS:80 BYTES FROM 0000:0000 (051)\nMachine_1:(vol=050V, str=023)";`, `"+DATA:BYTESFROM()\nMachine ,=Vol:str()"`, `i == 6` and `i == 7`. Try those :)

Comment: The key is simply to change the values of i, as the `strtok()` function will return many matched instances, of course you only want some of those.

Comment: It's okay, just experiment with it, it's a clever function :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code explain the basic idea.

```
#include "stdlib.h"        

float vol = 0, str = 0;
char * ptr = buf;

/* first vol */
ptr = strchr(ptr, '=');
if (NULL == ptr) {
  /* error handling */
}
ptr++;

vol = strtof(ptr, &ptr);

/* next str */
ptr = strchr(ptr, '=');
if (NULL == ptr) {
  /* error handling */
}
ptr++;

str = strtof(ptr, &ptr);

/* Now you can store vol & str to anywhere */
```